# SQL over clause PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-join, window-functions

Struggling to get the over partition by clause working with multiple tables that I want the sum values from.

Example:
Table1

```
Uidx as autonumber,
RepNumber int,
TransDT smalldatetime,
ProductNumber int,
Cost money,
```

Table2

```
Uidx as autonumber,
T1Uidx int,
PaymentAmount money,

Select RepNumber,ProductNumber,
TotalCost = sum(Cost)  OVER (PARTITION BY RepNumber) ,
TotalPayments = IsNull(sum(PaymentAmount),0)  OVER (PARTITION BY RepNumber) 
from Table1 Left outer join
     Table2 on Table2.T1Uidx = Table1.Uidx
Where TransDT between '3/1/2018' and '3/31/2018'
```

'Once I add the Left outer Join to the query it takes FOREVER!.
'I checked the indexs 
'I do have some null values (I can use isnull around the payment field)
'Table size Table1 about 32million
'Table size Table2 about 100million

I would like an output similiar to:

```
RepNumber,ProductNumber,TransDT,TotalCost,TotalPayments
123,999,1/1/2018,50.00,25.00
123,999,1/2/2018,50.00,5.00
456,222,1/4/2018,50.00,40.00
456,333,1/5/2018,50.00,10.00
```

Any suggestion would be great,.

As long as I DO NOT include the left outer inner works like a champ.
However as soon as I include the left outer join it gets very slow.
I would apperciate any advice you may give.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
Select t1.RepNumber, t1.ProductNumber,
       sum(t1.Cost)  OVER (PARTITION BY t1.RepNumber) as TotalCost, 
       IsNull(sum(t2.PaymentAmount)  OVER (PARTITION BY t1.RepNumber), 0) as TotalPayments
from Table1 t1 Left outer join
     Table2 t2
     on t2.T1Uidx = t1.Uidx
Where t1.TransDT between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-31';
```

You are generating a lot of rows, so I'm not surprised that the query is slow.

You can try indexes:  `table1(TransDT, Uix, RepNumber, ProductNumber, cost)` and `table2(T1Uidx, PamentAmount)`.  These are covering indexes and might help the query.

Comment: Thank you so much that works great not to bad on the time either.

Comment: Hey one more question I always use with (nolock) I noticed you did not? Could you tell me why.

Comment: @JustAnthony . . . https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/.